# Reorg existing bitbucket repo without losing older files

Tags: git, bitbucket

We have some nginx configs in bitbucket that are several years old. Some are stale, others are no longer used. In either case, no one is using bitbucket to manage the configs so I'd like to get some newly refactored configs under version control. I'm a newbie with git/bitbucket and I'm not sure the best way to start over from scratch without losing these existing files. The current directory structure is similar to this but with 15-20 files in each directory:

```
nginx
 -> include
    file1.conf
    file2.conf
    fileN.conf 
 -> html
    500.html
    400.html
nginx.dev.conf
nginx.prod.conf
other.conf
```

The new structure we're working on is similar to the above but will be simpler and we'll use templated configs that we can process with Ansible for various environments.

What is the best way to archive the existing repo layout so I can add and commit the initial revisions of these new directories and files?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question right, you can...

1. Initialize your folder as a git repository with `git init`
2. Begin tracking all of the files with `git add .`
3. Commit the current state of the folder with `git commit -m "Initial commit"`
4. Make changes and commit them freely. You will always be able to create a new branch and revert to your initial commit.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I did a good job of explaining what I'm trying to do. In the existing repo there is a directory called `html`, it will be going away with the refactoring along with its contents and a few other .conf files. What's the best way to "move" those out of the way so I can commit and push the newly refactored files and directory structure?